# Merge C# assemblies and create a nuget package

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, ilmerge

I have a solution that generates DLLs. There are good reasons to have multiple DLLs and I cannot just combine all of the dll projects into one, so I am using `ilmerge` to generate a single DLL as my final product. The `ilmerge` is done in the post-build.

The problem that I have is that I would like to create a `nuget` package using this generated DLL.

Normally, you could use this in the post build:

```
c:\NuGet.exe pack "$(ProjectPath)" -Symbols -OutputDir "\\Some Path\NuGet Packages"
```

This uses your solution's target to create the `nuget` package. The problem, of course, is that the target that the solution has is not the target that I want to use.

I could use a `nuspec` file. The problem with that is that I want to use the version number of the DLL as the version number of the `nuget` package.

So, my issue could be solved in a couple of different ways:

1. Create some sort of project that has `MyPackage.dll` as a target but that doesn't otherwise do anything.
2. Somehow create a `nuspec` file that uses the version number of the DLL file as the `nuget` version.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> > Somehow create a nuspec file that uses the version number of the DLL file as the nuget version.

$version$ replacement token can be user more details here http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference